# Rendering ember component outside parent template

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, javascriptmvc

Imagine the following situation. I have a sidebar positioned absolutely and then some more stuff positioned absolutely within that sidebar. In that sidebar I have a button, which shows a menu, the template looks like this:

```
<button>Click me</button>
{{#if shouldDisplayMenu}}
    {{view App.MyMenu}}
{{/if}}
```

What I like about this solution and want to keep is that the menu in the template is defined right next to the button, making for nice maintainability.

The problem is that I want the menu to be positioned relative to the viewport, i.e. rendered to document.body and positioned using position absolute. This way it will render into the sidebar and cause a scrollbar to be visible because I have already reset positioning context via position relative in one of the parent elements.

Is there any way I can keep {{view App.MyMenu}} where it is now, but have it render to body (perhaps using outlets or some other mechanism)? What is the recommended pattern for a situation like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to render views in `ember` with related context. I present four approaches *(i think the first is more likely what you are looking for)* :

**1.** If the view is required to be placed somewhere out of a handlebars template, it is possible to use jQuery to place the rendered content wherever it is required to be.

*(since the replacement of the view element is happening after `didInsertElement` it is probably required to also add styles to not show the element eg `display:none` , and show it after it has been repositioned)*

**Example**
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gotabore/1/edit

**2.** Use `{{render}}` helper to render the view in place if that place is somewhere in another template. Although i'm not certain about the context requirements, this helper is pretty flexible (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper).

**Example**
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xibayava/1/edit

**3.** Use `{{outlet}}` helper to render the view based on what is specified within the visited `route`. (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/)

**Example**
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tiyuqenu/1/edit

**4.** Use a `ContainerView` to push a view programmatically anywhere it is required to be.

**Example**
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoyujeqi/1/edit

---

**UPDATE for approach 4:** *for versions equal or greater than 1.8.x , to avoid the error mentioned in http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_global-lookup-of-views , it is possible to specify a property associated to the `ContainerView` as shown in the following example*

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/difayakeki/1/edit?html,js,output

---

***related code***

**approach 1**

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    This is index<br/>
    {{view App.TestView}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    This is the test view<br/>
    <b>{{myProp}}</b>
  </script>

  <div id="a-div" style="background-color:lightgray">
    This is a div somewhere,<br/>
  </div>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  myProp:"index controller prop"
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  placeTestViewSomewhere:function(){

    var theTestView = this.$(".my-test-view").detach();
    $("#a-div").append(theTestView);

  }.on("didInsertElement")
});

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"test",
  classNames:["my-test-view"]
});
```

**approach 2**

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    This is index<br/>

    <div style="background-color:lightgray">
    This is a div in index template with render helper,<br/>
    {{render "test"}}
  </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    This is the test view<br/>
    <b>{{myProp}}</b>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  placeTestViewSomewhere:function(){

//     var theTestView = this.$(".my-test-view").detach();
//     $("#a-div").append(theTestView);

  }.on("didInsertElement")
});

App.TestController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  myProp:"test controller prop"
});

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"test"
});
```

**approach 3**

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
    <div style="background-color:lightgray">
    This is a div in application template with outlet helper,<br/>
    {{outlet "test-outlet"}}
  </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    This is index<br/>

  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    This is the test view<br/>
    <b>{{myProp}}</b>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render("index");
    this.render('test', {   // the template to render
      into: 'application',                // the template to render into
      outlet: 'test-outlet'             // the name of the outlet in that template
    });
  }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  placeTestViewSomewhere:function(){

//     var theTestView = this.$(".my-test-view").detach();
//     $("#a-div").append(theTestView);

  }.on("didInsertElement")
});

App.TestController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  myProp:"test controller prop"
});

App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"test"
});
```

**approach 4**

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
    <div style="background-color:lightgray">
    This is a div in application template with view helper and a view container,<br/>
    {{view Ember.ContainerView viewName="my-menu-container"}}
  </div>

  </div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    This is index<br/>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="test">
    This is the test view<br/>
    <b>{{myProp}}</b>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  myProp:"index controller prop"
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  placeTestViewSomewhere:function(){

    var theTestView = App.TestView.create({});
    theTestView.set("context",this.get("context"));
    this.get("parentView.my-menu-container").pushObject(theTestView);

  }.on("didInsertElement")
});


App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"test"
});
```

---

**UPDATE for approach 4:**

**js**

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  containerView:Em.ContainerView
});
```

**hbs**

```
{{view view.containerView viewName="my-menu-container"}}
```

Comment: 'Approach 4' worked perfectly for a problem I'm working on for creating popup views. Thank you very much.

Comment: This has to be one of the best answers to any question ever.  Nice work!