# Ember 1.13, view lookup

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Prior to ember 1.13 i was using

```
  var containerView = Em.View.views[view_id];
```

to get the ContainerView instance with the view id and manually adding childViews to this container view, which used to work just fine.

As of ember 1.13 this view lookup is not supported. What is the recommended way of doing this?

The problem is there are multiple instances of the same containerView with different id's. So i need to get the right instance of containerView from lookup.

Thanks

**Update:**

I have a parent (widget) component: 
    parentComponent.hbs

.....

```
{{input value=someBinding1 click='showCalendar'}}
{{calendar-component month=month1 disableBefore=disableBefore1}}

{{input value=someBinding2 click='showCalendar'}}
{{calendar-component month=month2 disableBefore=disableBefore2}}

{{input value=someBinding3 click='showCalendar'}}
{{calendar-component month=month3 disableBefore=disableBefore3}}
```

.....

So essentially i can have multiple date(input) fields which when clicked should show up a calendar component. If i write the code as above it would create 3 (or as many date fields) instances of the calendar component. These number of date fields are dynamic. I did not wanted to create so many calendar components as i see sluggish performance on mobile devices.

So what i did was:

.....

```
{{input value=someBinding1 click='showCalendar'}}
{{calendar-container-view id='calendarContainerView1'}}

{{input value=someBinding2 click='showCalendar'}}
{{calendar-container-view id='calendarContainerView2'}}

{{input value=someBinding3 click='showCalendar'}}
{{calendar-container-view id='calendarContainerView2'}}
```

.....

And **calendar-container-view**  had an empty **childViews** array to start. 
When user clicks on input field i get the corresponding containerView instance using Em.View.views[containerViewId] and append the calendar instance to it. 
When another input is clicked i remove it from old parent containerView and add it to the new container view. 
So there is only one calendar instance created by **parentComponent.js** and removed and added to container view.

Hope it makes sense. I can create a jsbin if need be.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The recommended way of doing this is to restructure your code not to use views. If you do need to use views, arrange your code in such a way that this kind of manual lookup is not required. If you would post a skeleton version of your code so we could see what you are trying to do, maybe we could provide more help. For example, who is creating these multiple instances of the containerView? What are they connected to? Who is trying to add childViews to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could operate your **logic by model instances** instead of `views` (I mean model concept here, it could be some `array` of objects or `records array`).

It's clear you have `model` (as some array), since you mentioned `multiple instances`.

You might do:

```
{{!-- list of input fields --}}
{{#each model as |item|}}
  {{item-input-field item=item value=item.someBinding1 clickInput="setCurrentItemWhenInstanceClick"}}
{{/each}}

{{!-- and one calendar-component --}}
{{#if currentItem}}
  {{calendar-component item=currentItem month=currentMonth disableBefore=currentDisableBefore}}
{{/if}}
```

where `item-input-field` is a `component`, that extends `input` and pass it's `item` up to parent component or controller through action `clickInput` (**action up**).

Then `setCurrentItemWhenInstanceClick` action in parent component (or controller) should set `currentItem`, `currentMonth` and `currentDisableBefore` data (**data down** to `calendar-component`), so your `calendar-component` will be shown.

Comment: Thanks Artych, only question i have here is regarding HTML, how to add this calendar-component as child/sibling of the clicked input(HTML) filed. When another field is clicked, then remove it from the old input and add to the this new clicked input.

Comment: use jquery detach + append on `didInsertElement`, details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24162549/4950029 (bullet #1 only!)

Comment: OK, I think it will work this way. My only concern here was, is this the Ember-ish way of doing things? I mean adding remove DOM elements using jQuery?

Comment: I think jQuery is essential part of Ember if we are talking about DOM operations.